# set_exception_handler() expects the argument (exception_handler) to be a valid callback

Tags: php, error-handling

I have the following code:

```
namespace Google\Ads\GoogleAds\Examples\BasicOperations;

set_exception_handler('exception_handler');


function exception_handler($exception) {
echo "Uncaught exception: " , $exception->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

And get the following error (PHP 7.3):

> Warning: set_exception_handler() expects the argument
>   (exception_handler) to be a valid callback

It seems like the namespace has to be used to reference the exception handler function - such as set_error_handler("MyNamespace\my_error_handler"); - but I have not found an example that works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the namespace in there too,that's why it was not working.

```
set_exception_handler('Google\Ads\GoogleAds\Examples\BasicOperations\exception_handler');
```

instead of :

```
set_exception_handler('exception_handler');
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, this works too

```
set_exception_handler(array($this,'exception_handler'));
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
<?php

namespace Google\Ads\GoogleAds\Examples\BasicOperations;

set_exception_handler('Google\Ads\GoogleAds\Examples\BasicOperations\exception_handler');

throw new \Exception('test');

function exception_handler($exception) {
    echo "Uncaught exception: " , $exception->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

https://3v4l.org/bbmL1